# Explain these Colab warnings for my valid SVG code

Tags: validation, svg, google-colaboratory

I put the following code into a code cell in Google Colab:

```
%%svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(100,100,255); stroke-width:3; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

The result is properly executed and rendered but the code itself is embellished with red markings at the beginning of each tag and there is a red vertical line at the right border of the cell to indicate some warnings.

The code itself has been validated by https://validator.w3.org/

Please help me understand what is wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: standalone SVG files require namespaces - at the very least the SVG namespace to be defined so your file is invalid.

Comment: @RobertLongson Unfortunately, the suggested fix does not solve the issue because the symptoms are exactly the same with or without the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red markings are gone now. It was only a Colab bug after they introduced a new feature highlighting syntax issues. This new feature treated the code as written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the namespace: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in the root element (`<svg>`).

A SVG document is a XML document, which is a general markup language. The application that reads the file/document needs to know what "language" the element uses.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(100,100,255); stroke-width:3; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested fix does not solve the issue because the symptoms are exactly the same with or without the namespace.